# Wolframalpha and emathelp show different answers for limits

Tags: calculus

I have an infinite series of

$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\right]
$$

to test if it is convergent or divergent.

**My attempt:**

I first split the infinite series into:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1\right) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$$

And then performed a divergence test on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1\right)$ which gives me:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}1=1$$

Since the limit is $1$ $(\neq 0)$, hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\cos\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ is divergent too.

However, my TA told me that the infinite series is convergent. And when I used wolframalpha ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=infinite%20series&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D%20-%3E%221%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22infinite%20series%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%221-cos%28pi%2Fn%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumvariable%22%7D%20-%3E%22n%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D%20-%3E%22infinity%22)) to solve for the infinite series, it shows convergence. But when I used emathhelp ([here](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-2/series-calculator/?f=1-cos%28pi%2Fn%29&var=&a=1&b=inf&steps=on)), it shows divergent.

**Question:**

So is my TA and wolframalpha correct? Or am I or emathelp correct?

Comment: Splitting a convergent series into the difference of two divergent series.  Not a useful thing to do.

Comment: Thank you GEdgar. The problem is how do I know if it’s convergent if I don’t spilt it? In other words, I should never spilt an infinite series unless I know it is convergent?

Comment: We should add the hyotheses: if any two of the series are convergent, then so is the third, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \pm b_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \pm \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ holds.  So: if you split the series and the two new series turn out to be convergent, you are OK.

Comment: Thank you. What if after I spilt and found that one is diverging and the other is converging? Then what does it tell me of the original series?

Comment: As I said, if any two converge, then all three converge.  So if $\sum a_n$ converges and $\sum b_m$ diverges, we conclude $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot split the series into difference of two series since each of them is divergent. Use the fact that $0 \leq 1-\cos x \leq \frac {x^{2}} 2$ and use comparison test.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the fast response. But my professor told us that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \pm b_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \pm \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$. Why can I not apply this to here?

Comment: That result is true **only for convergent series**. You cannot apply it to two divergent series.  @IM_LOST

Comment: @IM_LOST For a simple example $\sum (1-1) $ is convergent since all the terms are $0$. But you cannot write it as $\sum1 -\sum 1$.

Comment: oh. Thank you. Allow me to clarify. If the splitting can only be used for convergent series, then how would I know if the original series is convergent or not. The reason I am asking is because my professor did an example of splitting on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n-5^n}{3^n}$ and ended up having $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{3^n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5^n}{3^n}$. Then he claimed that since the second term diverges, then the original series also diverges despite the first term converges.

Comment: You cannot always determine convergence or divergence of $\sum (a_n-b_n)$ by splitting it. If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are both convergent you can split it and conclude that the original series is also convergent. But in cases lie the one in your question you cannot use splitting at all. You have to think of some other test for convergence. @IM_LOST

Comment: So what the professor did is wrong? Since the original series is divergent, so he should not split the terms at all?

Comment: @IM_LOST I am surprised at what emathelp showed. To repeat, you cannot split the given series into two parts.

Comment: Thank you. Let me read more about splitting of infinite series. While I think what you mentioned makes sense, I then wonder why my professor split the infinite series without knowing if it converges or not; and then claim that it diverges.

Comment: @IM_LOST What your professor might have done is $\sum \frac{2^n - 5^n}{3^n} \ - \sum \frac{2^n}{3^n}$ and if the sum is convergent then the sum with $5^n$ is also convergent which is false.

Comment: $\displaystyle 1 - \cos\left(\pi \over n\right) \sim {\pi^{2} \over 2}\,\color{red}{1 \over n^{2}}\ \mbox{as}\ n \to \infty$. So many comments and nobody mention this fact !!!.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor,

$$1-\cos\frac\pi n=\frac{\pi^2}{2n^2}-\frac{\pi^4}{4!n^4}+\cdots$$

and the individual terms form converging series. Then is not difficult to show that the global series is absolutely converging.

Answer (score 0):

Not only it does converge as explained in comments and answers but you could also have a good approximation of the infinite sum.

Since we now the values for the first angles, write
$$S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{6 } \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)\right)+\sum _{n=7}^{\infty } \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)\right)$$ that is to say
$$S=\frac{1}{4} \left(25-2 \sqrt{2}-2 \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}\right)+\sum _{n=7}^{\infty } \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)\right)$$

Now
$$a_n=1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)=\frac{\pi ^2}{2 n^2}-\frac{\pi ^4}{24 n^4}+\frac{\pi ^6}{720 n^6}-\frac{\pi
   ^8}{40320 n^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=7}^\infty n^{-2k}=\zeta (2 k)-1-2^{-2 k}-3^{-2 k}-4^{-2 k}-5^{-2 k}-6^{-2 k}$$
$$\sum_{n=7}^\infty a_n=-\frac{5369 \pi ^2}{7200}+\frac{39931361 \pi ^4}{311040000}-\frac{47464376609 \pi
   ^6}{33592320000000}-\frac{423805258161097 \pi ^8}{967458816000000000}+\frac{\pi
   ^{12}}{680400}-\frac{\pi ^{16}}{381024000}$$

So

$$S\approx 4.87071896177$$ while the value computed with unlimited precision is
$S=4.87071896189\cdots$

These numbers are not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.